# php mysql show whole record when name is clicked

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have records in the mysql database. in the browser, I need to display just the id or the name and it should be clickable, when clicked it should show the other info like email, phone etc..
I can list the names using SELECT but not sure how to link it and show the data..if there is a jquery method to display the data in a div, it would be good ..please advise me how to start with..thanks.

ex

```
<a href="">rob</a>
<a href="">mike</a>
<a href="">bob</a>
```

i guess the url will have the remaining data for that record.
clicking on rob, then result should be

```
Rob
Phone - $phone
Email - $email
Age -   $age
```

Answer (score 1):

make your href link send to another page where you have all stats printed. The best way is having href by ID. So.

```
<a href="yoursite.com?id=1">rob</a>
<a href="yoursite.com?id=2">mike</a>
<a href="yoursite.com?id=3">bob</a>
```

Or you can make a toolip out of it and hide all information into dispay none "bubble" :P
http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/simple-tooltip-w-jquery-css/

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is use an ajax to compare the data without a refreshing page so here's my code example that you can improve as your needs :

INDEX.HTML

```
<!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>


        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">


        $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $("#get").click(function()
                {
                                        var name = $("#name").val();
                    $('#1').load("getdata.php?name=" +name);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
         NAME : <input type="textbox" id="name" >
         <button id="get">Get Name Data</button> 
         <div id="1" name='divku'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

GETDATA.PHP

```
<?php
    $name = $_GET['name'];
    getname($name);

function getname($name)
{

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if (!$con)
    {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("stackoverflow", $con);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user where name = '" . $name . "'" );

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

 echo $row[0] . $row[1] . $row [2];

}
mysql_close($con);

}
?>
```

I hope this could solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method,

```
foreach ($detailedArr as $arr)  {
    echo '<a href="javascript:;" name="a_name" id="a_'. $arr['id'] .'" >'. $arr['name'] .'</a>';
    echo '<div name="div_detail" id="div_'. $arr['id'] .'" style="clear:both;display:none;" >';
    echo 'email : '. $arr['email'];
    echo '</div>';
}
```

here `$detailedArr` is the array which is having all your records  and you can change the design based on your requirement. and in your Javascript code

```
$(function() {
    $("[name=a_name]").click(function() {
        var clkId = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
        $("[name=div_detail]").hide({animate:'slow'});
        $("#div_"+clkId).show({animate:'slow'});
    });
});
```

here I have done with jQuery so you have to include jQuery library